# Uncaught Error: You did not set a valid publishable key. Rails 4.2.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments, figaro-ruby

I've went back to a 'was-all-perfect' project I did last year January. Now..I've upgraded to rails 4.2.4 and upgraded my [Figaro to 1.1.1](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro). All seems well but I got this stripe error. I really dont see an issue. But I've noticed that my `head` do not have the stripe key anymore:

**layouts/application.html.erb:**

```
<%= tag :meta, :name => "stripe-key", :content => STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY %>
```

**initializers/stripe.rb:**

```
Stripe.api_key = ENV["stripe_api_key"]
STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY = ENV["stripe_publishable_key"]
```

**config/application.yml:**

```
stripe_api_key: sk_test****
stripe_publishable_key: pk_test****
```

Is there a change somewhere in Rails 4.2.4

Answer (score -1):

I'll add an answer if in the future I make this mistake again. It looks like, in my Gemfile, figaro should not be placed in the development group but rather outside. Now my stripe works fine.